# How to delete (non-favorite) songs that are stored in internal memory in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, android-activity, media-player

I have hundreds of songs on the phone and I would like just delete non-favorite songs. Is it possible by code? Using the Android's default music player?

Comment: You'd better post your question here: android.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com